# Combine two datasets for a combined chart

Tags: algorithm

Say I have two lists with x and y points like this.

```
Dataset 1
[[1.0,2.0],
 [2.0,2.4],
 [3.0,2.8],
 [4.0,3.5],
 [5.0,4.0]]

Dataset 2
[[2.4,1.0],
 [2.8,1.0],
 [3.1,1.0],
 [4.0,1.0]]
```

I want to add them together so the result looks like this

```
[[1.0,2.0],
 [2.0,2.4],
 [2.4,2.6],
 [2.4,3.6],
 [2.8,3.7],
 [3.0,3.8],
 [3.1,3.9],
 [4.0,4.5],
 [4.0,3.5],
 [5.0,4.0]]
```

So by combining the red and blue graph below the result should be the grey line.
Are there any known algorithms that can be used to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match the picture here.

Comment: Christ, when you give an example in the future, please do your best to make sure it's not grossly flawed and inaccurate. I didn't appreciate having to make substantial edits to it to make your question sensible.

Comment: Totally guessing here, but it seems like you want to 1) recognize that the y value for data set 2 is always 1, but only between the x values of 2.4 and 4, and then 2) add 1 to the y value of any point in data set 1 where x is between 2.4 and 4. At least, that's what the picture looks like (kinda). Otherwise, since your x values don't match in the two sets, it's a bit difficult to decide exactly what you want...

Comment: Sorry about that, i have corrected the numbers.

Comment: Either I don't understand the question, or you just reverted the (correct) edits of @SlaterTyranus. The question in its current form is self-contradictory and makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you are dealing with linear relationships?  Or can your data represent any arbitrary relationship.  For simplicity, let's assume you are dealing with linear data.

1. Take your first data set, and fit it to a line.
2. Write a Java function to return the y value for any x on the line whose equation you have derived in step 1.
3. Set 2 looks like a typical step or pulse function (these are nonanalytical functions, i.e. usual conventions such as those that apply to calculus are invalid).  You can write a Java function for this like so

   static double stepFunction(double x) {
        return (x <= 2.2 || x > 4.0)
            ? 0.0
            : 1.0
    }
4. Your plot is simply a sum of the two functions, i.e.

   y2(x) = y1(x) + stepFunction(x)

Answer (score 0):

you can't add two groups of number-pairs if they don't share the same coordinates...

try to interpret both of you point sets as interpolations, and redefine a common domain for the functions where the two datasets can be added for example `[1.0:0.1:5.0]`